# How to deconstruct arrays of arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm working with an API and after I try to clean up the data, I got an array of arrays of arrays:

```
arr = [[[{name: "john"}],[{name: "jack"}]],[[{name: "joe"}],[{name: "bob"}]]]
```

How can I clean this up to something like this:

```
arr = [{name: "john"},{name: "jack"},{name: "joe"},{name: "bob"}]
```

Comment: Look into `Array.flat` and `Array.flatMap`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), providing `Infinity` as the `depth` argument to flatten all sub-arrays recursively:

```js
const arr = [[[{name: "john"}],[{name: "jack"}]],[[{name: "joe"}],[{name: "bob"}]]];

const flattened = arr.flat(Infinity);

console.log(flattened);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case calling `arr.flat().flat()` would do the trick.

Comment: Using `.flat(2)` would be more suitable imo

Comment: @jsejcksn's answer is _flat-out_ better ;) (see what I did there?)